# How to open the correct version of Excel when 2 versions are installed

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access VBA script that exports to Excel.  It opens the workbook, copies & formats the data and saves the workbook.  It's worked for years.  It worked on my old system with Office 13, and it works on my new system with Office 16.  Now I'm trying to run this on another PC that was just set up - it has Office 13 installed, but may also have the Office 16 version installed that came with the new PC.

When I manually open Excel, Excel 2013 opens as it should.  When my Access code runs and tries to open Excel, it seems to be going to the new version - and the code stops working, I think because the Office 16 account isn't set up and when Excel opens it goes to the Office 16 activation screen instead of opening the workbook.

The export macro code is

```
    Public Function Export_data(Optional table As String, Optional opt As String = "")

Set wb_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
wb_app.Visible = False
wb_app.displayalerts = False

path = DLookUp("[report folder]", "folder")

If opt <> "" Then
    FileName = path & "\" & opt & ".xlsm"
    Set wb_obj = wb_app.workbooks.Open(FileName)
    End If
```

The error occurs at "wb_app.workbooks.open" with the error "Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class."  When I set .Visible to True and look at what Excel is doing, it's going to the activation screen for the Office 16 account.

How can I change the VBA code to direct it to the correct version of Excel?

Comment: final note - the new PC has Access 2016 which is where I'm running the code, but Excel 2013.

Comment: Do note there's no such thing as _Office 13_. 2 digits numbers are meant to indicate the internal version number. Version 13 got skipped as an unlucky number, 2007 -> 12, 2010 -> 14

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the version by using the 2-digit office version at the end of the file, e.g.:

```
Set wb_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application.14") 'Office 2010
```

You can look in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT to see what's available. Of course, you can query the registry using VBA if you want.

Comment: Thanks - I can manually inspect the registry and find the entry.  I didn't want to put something in the code specific to one machine though, so I tried to use VBA to query the registry, with no success - I think I found the right code, but didn't seem to have permissions to read the registry.  In the meantime, the IT tech responsible for the new PC removed the extra version of Excel, which fixed the problem.